Does the Bible apply to us believers at all?
I was told I have been living in a lie for the past 36 years that the Bible does not apply to me or anyone today that the Bible is just a Jewish book and applies only to and about Israel . I’m very disappointed and confused about this all and also was told I don’t need to be saved nothing to be saved for I know the finish work on the cross was sufficient but that was just for Israel and I was told when I die I will cease to exist. I’ve studied out since dispensational mid acts to preterist and been learning this salvation of all trying to understand different views

Welcome to BHSX.  God bless you, Ellen,  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.  Valid questions here need a specific passage to examine.  I would beg to stridently differ from whoever told you the Bible is irrelevant.  The Bible is the Word of God to us seeking salvation because it reveals God.

Although the Bible was not directly written to anyone of us today, it was definitely written for us.  If we are to believe that the Bible's message is only for Jewish people, then how do we make sense of the following?
In Joshua chapters 2-6, we are introduced to Rahab, who appears to be a Canaanite woman who lived in Jericho.
Joshua 2:1 (LEB)

2 Then Joshua son of Nun secretly sent two men from Acacia Grove as
spies, saying, “Go, view the land, especially Jericho.” So they went,
and entered the house of a prostitute whose name was Rahab, and ⌊spent
the night⌋ there.

The Baker Encyclopedia of the Bible has an entry on Rahab:

Rahab (Person). Heroine of the battle of Jericho (Jos 2–6). Soon after
Moses’ death, God told Joshua that he and the people were to cross the
Jordan and occupy the land of promise. Before the crossing, however,
Joshua sent two spies into the land to reconnoiter the opposition, in
particular the fortified city of Jericho. Upon entering the city, the
spies found their way quickly to Rahab’s house, which was perhaps an
inn and/or a brothel. She apparently was a prostitute. News of the
arrival of spies was not long in reaching the king of Jericho, who
quite naturally demanded that Rahab divulge their whereabouts. She
cleverly admitted seeing them, but insisted that they had left the
city at nightfall. Actually, the spies were hiding under stalks of
flax on the roof of her house. When the king’s search party left
Jericho to hunt the spies, Rahab confessed to the spies the reason for
her complicity with the Israelites’ cause. She feared the God of the
Jews, believing that he would surely give them victory. “For the Lord
your God is God in heaven above and on the earth below” (Jos 2:11
NIV). For her help, the spies agreed to save Rahab and her family. The
sign was to be a cord of scarlet thread hanging from her window, the
same avenue the spies used to escape the city. Rahab and her family
were indeed the only survivors of the subsequent battle. They were led
to safety on Joshua’s command by the very men Rahab had saved. Jewish
tradition added to the biblical account the notion that Rahab married
Joshua after converting to faith in God, that her progeny included
eight priests and prophets, including Jeremiah. She was supposedly a
most beautiful woman who had become a prostitute at the early age of
10, but whose subsequent record exonerated her. A variant to the
tradition holds that Rahab was not a prostitute at all, but an
innkeeper, a suggestion advanced by the Targum’s euphemistic rendering
of prostitute as innkeeper. Rahab (KJV Rachab) became the wife of
Salmon and mother of Boaz, and thus an ancestor of Jesus (Mt 1:5).
Rahab is listed, along with Moses, David, Samson, and Samuel, as an
example of faith (Heb 11). Her deed is an example of good works and
justification (Jas 2:25).

 Walter A. Elwell and Barry J. Beitzel, “Rahab (Person),” Baker Encyclopedia of 
 the Bible (Grand Rapids, MI: Baker Book House, 1988), 1817.

Rahab was not a Jewish woman, and yet she was saved because she put her faith in the God of Israel, and her faith was proven genuine by her works.
Galatians 3:13–14 (LEB)

13 Christ redeemed us from the curse of the law by* becoming a curse
for us, because it is written, “Cursed is everyone who hangs on a
tree,” 14 in order that the blessing of Abraham might come to the
Gentiles in Christ Jesus, so that we might receive the promise of the
Spirit through faith.

Here, Paul says that the blessing of Abraham has indeed come to the Gentiles (non-Jewish people).  Salvation is found in Jesus Christ for both Jew and Gentile.  This does not mean all Scripture immediately applies to us today in the same way that it applied to the Jewish people in the Old Testament.  We have to examine the text of Scripture carefully and interpret it through the light of the New Testament, acknowledging that the Gospel is for the Jew first, and then to the Gentile/Greek.
Romans 1:16–17 (LEB)

16 For I am not ashamed of the gospel, for it is the power of God for
salvation to everyone who believes, to the Jew first and also to the
Greek. 17 For the righteousness of God is revealed in it from faith to
faith, just as it is written, “But the one who is righteous by faith
will live.”

Revelation says that the sacrificial blood of the Lamb has bought people from every tribe, language, people and nation - not just the Jewish people:
Revelation 5:6–10 (LEB)

6 And I saw in the midst of the throne and of the four living
creatures and in the midst of the elders a Lamb standing as though
slaughtered, having seven horns and seven eyes, which are the seven
spirits of God sent into all the earth. 7 And he came and took the
scroll from the right hand of the one who was seated on the throne.
8 And when he took the scroll, the four living creatures and the
twenty-four elders fell down before the Lamb, each one of whom had a
harp and golden bowls full of incense, which are the prayers of the
saints. 9 And they were singing a new song, saying,
“You are worthy to take the scroll
and to open its seals,
because you were slaughtered,
and bought people for God by your blood
from every tribe and language and people and nation,
10 and made them a kingdom and priests to our God,
and they will reign on the earth.”

I hope this gives you some assurance that salvation is open to you if you have faith in Jesus Christ.  These passages demonstrate that fact.  If someone tells you that you have gotten your faith all wrong your whole life, they probably are not very familiar with the Scriptures.  Just keep reading and studying, and balance your interactions with people by digging deep into the Word of God.  I'm a partial preterist myself, but I could see a full-preterist having issues with any reassurance of Jesus coming back again, since that position would hold that He already has in 70AD.  There is plenty of information to indicate that Jesus has yet to completely fulfill His judgment of the world.

Jesus' return is going to be visible:

Acts 1:9–11 (LEB)

9 And after he* had said these things, while* they were watching, he
was taken up, and a cloud received him from their sight. 10 And as
they were staring into the sky while* he was departing, behold, two
men in white clothing stood by them 11 who also said, “Men ⌊of
Galilee⌋, why do you stand there looking into the sky? This Jesus who
was taken up from you into heaven like this will come back in the same
way you saw him departing into heaven!”


Jesus' coming judgment will be to all the nations:

Matthew 25:31–34 (LEB)

31 Now when the Son of Man comes in his glory and all the angels with
him, then he will sit on his glorious throne. 32 And all the nations
will be gathered before him, and he will separate them from one
another like a shepherd separates the sheep from the goats. 33 And he
will place the sheep on his right and the goats on the left. 34 Then
the king will say to those on his right, ‘Come, you who are blessed by
my Father. Inherit the kingdom prepared for you from the foundation of
the world!


The dead will be raised:

1 Corinthians 15:22–24 (LEB)

22 For just as in Adam all die, so also in Christ all will be made
alive. 23 But each in his own group: Christ the first fruits, then
those who are Christ’s at his coming, 24 then the end, when he hands
over the kingdom to the God and Father, when he has abolished all rule
and all authority and power.


There will be a new heaven and earth:

Revelation 21:1–4 (LEB)

21 And I saw a new heaven and a new earth, for the first heaven and
the first earth had passed away, and the sea did not exist any longer.
2 And I saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven
from God, prepared like a bride adorned for her husband. 3 And I heard
a loud voice from the throne saying,
“Behold, the dwelling of God is with humanity,
and he will take up residence with them,
and they will be his people
and God himself will be with them.
4 And he will wipe away every tear from their eyes,
and death will not exist any longer,
and mourning or wailing or pain will not exist any longer.
The former things have passed away.”

These are just some examples that I think are clearly still on a future horizon of things to come.  Hopefully all this helps.  Take care.

I have spoken to this person and he came back with this....>Ok , in 1st Corinthians chapter 15 verses 1 thru 5 it uses the phrase ( according to the scriptures) in fact it uses it twice , he died according to the scriptures, he arose according to theto scriptures, at that time they only had and knew the Old Testament.
Show me what scriptures in the old testament say that???

You guys write yourself into the storyIn the law, prophets, psalms! Yahweh has nothing to do withto do heathens, he tells his people to kill them , to destroy women, children and everything leave nothing un destroyed.
He calls out one nation and tells that nation he loves them and only them, he gives that one nation only a law, feasts days, give only them a temple, priests and etc.
he does nothing for the heathens <<<< where did he change his mind all of a sudden he loves those that he told his people to destroy????

Mary was told she will have a baby and that baby will save HIS PEOPLE!!
He will redeem his people!!!
No heathens was HIS PEOPLE!!
These are facts!!!Go read for yourself and find theses answers..

Ask yourself this. If when it was revealed that the Gospel was going to the Gentiles, and it actually meant that the target was Universal Humanity from now on, and this leveled the playing field so to speak. How is it that Paul is still using such language as Kinsman when there is supposed to be no difference between Jew and Gentile?

Unless of course Jew and Gentile were both Kinsman of Paul. Also, think about John chapter 3 where Jesus tells Nicodemus that God so loved the world that whoever believed in that world would receive everlasting life. Why didn't Nicodemus fall over or exclaim utter astonishment of such a revelation that now Universal Humanity was included in all Israel's promises? Simply because Universal Humanity is never on the radar in the New Testament!

@EllenGibson that's a lot of material to cover.  If the person you're talking to is that antagonistic towards you, it might not be worth giving them an answer.  If you decide to move forward and continue talking with them, you'll have to address one issue at a time.  I would recommend Dr. Michael Brown's material on Answering Jewish Objections to Jesus, and that should give you a good idea about OT prophecies that Jesus fulfilled.  Another person would be Dr. Michael S. Heiser and his input in Deuteronomy 32 and Psalm 82.  God divorced the nations and kept Israel as His own inheritance.

@EllenGibson Psalm 82 has God condemning the gods of the nations as being unjust in their judgments, and the psalm ends saying, "8 Rise up, O God, judge the earth, because you shall inherit all the nations." It says He will inherit all the nations back to Himself.  These nations He previously disinherited or divorced in Deuteronomy 32:8-9 (LEB): "⌊When the Most High apportioned⌋ the nations, at his dividing up of the sons of humankind, he fixed the boundaries of the peoples, according to the number of the sons of God. 9 For Yahweh’s portion was his people, Jacob the share of his inheritance."

I agree with you Matthew and I have not responded back to this person I was just reading what they posted to me and yes that was alot . I was born into a Jewish Family even though I believed Jesus as the Messiah he even said to me I wasnt even that. I dont know what this person got themselves into worse of it all saying we will cease to exist. I cannot accept that...

@EllenGibson your acquaintance is badly confused. God never told Israel to destroy all heathens, that was a specific command for a specific time and place that explicitly does not include other Gentile nations. On the contrary, God promised to Abraham that "in thy seed shall all the nations of the earth be blessed". As Matthew says, that's a lot of material, this is just some low-hanging fruit.

I am going to answer your question with 2 parts
 the Bible does not apply to me or anyone today that the Bible is just a Jewish book and applies only to and about Israel 

The Bible is the universal message of God, If the Bible were only written to the Jews then we would not have verses like
Galatians 3:28 KJV

There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither bond nor free, there is neither male nor female: for ye are all one in Christ Jesus

Colossians 3:11 KJV

Where there is neither Greek nor Jew, circumcision nor uncircumcision, Barbarian, Scythian, bond nor free: but Christ is all, and in all.

Romans 3:29-30 KJV

Is he the God of the Jews only? is he not also of the Gentiles? Yes, of the Gentiles also: Seeing it is one God, which shall justify the circumcision by faith, and uncircumcision through faith.

also, the Bible being the universal word, we are to read it as it was given to us so that we would believe what Christ had come to do, and that Christ is indeed the son of God
2 Timothy 3:16-17 KJV

All scripture is given by inspiration of God, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for instruction in righteousness

John 20:31 KJV

But these are written, that ye might believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God; and that believing ye might have life through his name


the next one I don’t need to be saved nothing to be saved for I know the finish work on the cross was sufficient but that was just for Israel and I was told when I die I will cease to exist
Knowing the finished work of the cross is not sufficient to be saved, many people have read the Gospel and seen the message of Christ and know what he died for but do not accept it. Those people are not saved, they revel in their sin and do not accept Gods grace given to us and are unrepentant.
John 3:18 KJV

He that believeth on him is not condemned: but he that believeth not is condemned already, because he hath not believed in the name of the only begotten Son of God.

John 3:16 KJV

For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.

Romans 10:9 KJV

That if thou shalt confess with thy mouth the Lord Jesus, and shalt believe in thine heart that God hath raised him from the dead, thou shalt be saved.

Whoever told you these things as said in your question truly does not know scripture, and greatly misinformed, the word of God applies to every person on this planet now and here to come, as without the word we would not know Christ is the son of God

hi a few hurdles - Jesus said he only came to the lost sheep of Israel, gentiles came after mainly with Paul.  David was also Begotten son.  There is nothing in the OT - 1 Cor 15:4 and that He was buried, and that He was raised the third day according to the Scriptures,.  This is only Pauls preaching - 2 Tim 2:8 Remember Jesus Christ, having been raised out from the dead, of the seed of David, according to my gospel,

@anothertheory Christ was sent to gather the lost sheep of Israel, he reinforces this with the words he says in Matthew 15:24 and also fullfills a prophecy, the people of Israel rejected Christ as their messiah. due note many times Christ has said everyone who believes in him shall be saved, he does not says jews who believes in me only shall be saved. Paul saying this is my Gospel Is referring to the gospel of grace given to him by the risen Christ to HIM and not the other apostles, that is why he uses the singular MY Gospel.

thanks - Romans 15:20 20 It has always been my ambition to preach the gospel where Christ was not known, so that I would not be building on someone else’s foundation. (doesnt look like inspiration from Jesus).  No OT about Jesus being raised!  - Matt 7:21 - Not everyone saying to Me, 'Lord, Lord,' will enter into the kingdom of the heavens, but the one doing the will of My Father in the heavens.

@anothertheory Romans 15:19 19 by the power of signs and wonders, by the power of the Spirit of God—so that from Jerusalem and all the way around to Illyricum I have fulfilled the ministry of the Gospel of Christ; follow by Romans 15:20. He is speaking of spreading the Gospel of Christ to places that has not yet heard of it, which are the gentiles.  Ephesians 3:8 8 To me, though I am the very least of all the saints, this grace was given, to preach to the Gentiles the unsearchable riches of Christ. Matt 7:21 refers to false believers so I am clueless as to why u put this here

Were clearly reading things different-what other foundation can he build on but Christ regardless if his preaching a new audience.  Jesus did not say go preach to the gentiles. Matt 7:21 - You said anyone who believes in Jesus will be saved, Jesus says no the one who does the will of the father.  also Luke 18: 18.  A certain ruler asked him, "Good teacher, what must I do to inherit eternal life?" 20.  You know the commandments: 'Do not commit adultery, do not murder, do not steal, do not give false testimony, honor your father and mother.' (says nothing about Jesus, other passages say God)

Paul was rejected in Asia - 2 Timothy 1:15 - 15You know that everyone in the Province of Asia has deserted me, including Phygelus and Hermogenes. Acts 21: 27-28 27 When the seven days were almost completed, the Jews from Asia, who had seen him in the temple, stirred up all the crowd, and laid hands on him, 28 crying out, “Men of Israel, help! This is the man who is teaching men everywhere against the people and the law and this place; moreover he also brought Greeks into the temple, and he has defiled this holy place.” [Jews and Gentiles did not agree or accept]
